# One-day-off error using Ice_Cube gem to schedule day_of_month events

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ice-cube

```
HOLIDAYS = Schedule.new(Date.new(2012,1,1))
HOLIDAYS.add_recurrence_rule Rule.yearly.month_of_year(:october).day_of_month(31)
```

When I check HOLIDAYS.occurs_on? for 10/31/12 I get FALSE, but when I check for 10/30/12 I get TRUE.

What am I doing wrong?

-- edit -- sample run

```
days =  Holidays::HALLOWEEN.occurrences(Date.today)
days.each do |day|
  Log.info day
end
Log.info Holidays::HALLOWEEN.occurs_on?(Date.new(2012,10,31))
Log.info Holidays::HALLOWEEN.occurs_on?(Date.new(2012,10,30))
Log.info Holidays::HALLOWEEN.occurs_on?(Date.new(2013,10,31))
Log.info Holidays::HALLOWEEN.occurs_on?(Date.new(2013,10,30))
```

Results in:

```
[09:22:15] INFO 2012-10-31 00:00:00 -0400
[09:22:15] INFO 2013-10-31 00:00:00 -0400
[09:22:15] INFO false
[09:22:15] INFO true
[09:22:15] INFO false
[09:22:15] INFO true
```

Comment: is it a leap year issue?

Comment: Don't think so; leap year doesn't affect the number of days in October, and I have the same problem for 2013.

Comment: Looking at this again, it's probably the -0400 that pushes us back into the previous day. How can I set that to zero, or use whole days, using this gem?

Comment: how about this?  `HOLIDAYS.add_recurrence_rule Rule.day_of_month(31).month_of_year(:october)`

Comment: https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube#time-zones-and-activesupport-vs-standard-ruby-time-classes

Answer (score 1):

By switching from Date.new(2012,10,31) to Time.utc(2012,10,31) I was able to get correct behavior.